# Javascript reference a form, change action url, then http get

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how to reference a form, change action url, then http get.

for example: 
if the input string starts with %

then i want to be able to change the form action to = UrlOne

if input string starts with "@"

form action = UrlTwo

etc..

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms

```
//get all forms on page
var collection = document.forms; 

//access particular form
var firstform = collection[0];

//get action attribute
var actionurl = firstform.getAttribute('action')

//compare action attribute
if ('foo' == actionurl) {
     firstform.setAttribute('action', 'bar'); //set action attribute
}
```